# Saving Switch State In Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, togglebutton

Whenever I open the app and click the switch, dark mode turns on and it stays in the position. However, if I relaunch the app, the switch goes back to default, and dark mode is still on. How would I do this in Kotlin?

Also, is there any reference code for this in Kotlin?

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at how to persist data with Android, there's plenty of documentation.

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences to save the switch state. Whenever the app launches, retrieve the state from the SharedPreferences to check whether the state is off/on. Read more here https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Answer (score 0):

Create Pref class for storing data.

```
class Prefs (private val context: Context)

private fun getSharedPreferences(prefsName: String) =
    context.getSharedPreferences(prefsName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

private val PREF_KEY = "pref_key"
private val KEY_VALUE = "key_value"
private val prefValue by lazy { getSharedPreferences(PREF_KEY) }

var currentModeDayNight: Boolean
    get() {
        return prefValue.getBoolean(KEY_VALUE, false)
    }
    set(value) {
        prefValue.edit().putBoolean(KEY_VALUE, value).apply()
    }
```

Then store data for default dayNightMode.

You may just need to restart your app. But keep in mind, that this code enables the Dark Mode System-wide, not just in App:

```
public static void setNightMode(Context target){

    UiModeManager uiManager = (UiModeManager) target.getSystemService(Context.UI_MODE_SERVICE);

    if (VERSION.SDK_INT <= 22) {
        uiManager.enableCarMode(0);
    }
    
    val pref = Pref(context)
    if (pref.currentModeDayNight) {
        pref.currentModeDayNight = false
        uiManager.setNightMode(UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    } else {
        pref.currentModeDayNight = true
        uiManager.setNightMode(UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    }
}
```